# htaccess change directory name into parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain that is used for redirects.

```
example.com/129dj9
```

It uses a 6 digit alphanumeric code. I would like to change `example.com/129dj9` into `example.com?code=129dj9` in order to redirect to another url.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/([a-z0-9]{6})
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example\.com?code={REQUEST_URI}
```

I want to ensure that the domain is `example.com` and also that the directory `/129dj9` is a 6-digit alphanumeric code. My code isn't working at all.

Comment: Step 1: Go figure out what a _host name_ actually is.

Comment: @cbroe answer my question bro.

Comment: 1. Not your bro. 2. You didn’t even manage to ask an actual _question_, so dial down the attitude maybe. 3. _Go inform yourself_ what “host name” means, so that you can realize what mistake you made above.

Comment: The part of checking the path can be done in the RewriteRule directly, that doesn’t need to be handed over to a RewriteCond to begin with. So check the host name for the desired match using the condition, and the path in the rule. (No leading slash for the latter, when configured in .htaccess context, that has been stripped off at that point already.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for such a complex `RewriteCond` here, instead try something like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z0-9]{6})$ https://example.com?code=$1 [END]
```

Note: it is always preferable to place such rules in the real http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess") if you have access to that configuration. Above rule will work in both scenarios.